# ASP.net webservice 401 error for some services only

Tags: asp.net, web-services, http-status-code-401

I have created a webservice in a ASP.net. All the access to the respective website is done through **HTTPS**. The service which I have added is only one among many others.

I am trying to access just for test purposes this service through Javascript (Ajax, json). The final target is actually Android.

I am getting the following message:

```
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

The main problem here is inconsistency: while my webservice in inaccessible, another previously written webservice is accessible. Another apparent inconsistency is that even if I tried a compromise solution by adding the needed methods to the accessible webservice, these methods themselves incur a 401 error.

So, my question is related to both "Why doesn't my webservice work" and "How is this supposed to work", with more emphasis on the latter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind !

Since I was oblivious to the depths of the code I was changing on our server, I did not know that the 401 error message is sent due to the way the code is organised. To access other services, I had to authenticate first through the authentication webservice.